Why doesn't my capacitor take the pressure off the pnp transistor briefly?
I am self-learning some electronics after seeing some "modular synthesizer" videos. I loaded LTspice (is this a good choice?) and started creatively guessing.
In the diagram below v1 and v2 are DC voltage sources.
The idea behind the circuit below was to show myself that v1 put too much voltage on the base of the PNP transistor to allow it to, um, transist.  The voltage on n004 is about 100 pico-volts; I'm calling that 0v. All that was fine, and if I reduced the voltage of v1 then n004 started showing some actual voltage.  All that was to my expectation.
Then I added the c1 capacitor.
My expectation was that it would soak up some voltage (?) briefly and when it got full, q1's base would be overpowered and n004 would show no voltage, just as before. However, while c1 was charging, I expected that q1 would flow and there would be a voltage on n004. This did not happen; I can't tell c1 does much of anything. How is my thinking wrong?

Edit

Ok, I had to mess with the simulation time and the value of the capacitor, but @periblepsis was right - I needed the uic parameter.  You can see how the capacitor is charging (green). At .5 seconds, v1 asserts itself and the blue line (v(n005) on the chart, but mislabeled as n004 on the circuit) drops to 0v.  The red line is the voltage on q1's base; as time goes on v1 keeps pouring it on.

Show more of the circuit. It's incomplete there. My first take would be simply to say that an ideal voltage source across an ideal capacitor and given the Spice ITS step means there's no difference. But the circuit is incomplete, so I can't say that yet.

That's the whole thing, thought I lost the grounding triangle dealio on the left.

Okay. So that's it. Spice goes through an ITS (where it works out the initial DC conditions) phase before simulation. That process will "see" that the capacitor is already charged by the voltage supply. So the time domain simulation will start with the capacitor already charged up.

I never would have figured that out.  What do I do about it?

Nothing with the existing circuit. There is no possible way that the capacitor voltage can be different from the voltage source at the beginning of the time domain run. Otherwise, supposing the capacitor voltage is zero and the voltage source is non-zero, then the very first thing that happens is an infinitely high current must occur to charge up the cap, since both are ideal devices. And that's not allowed. So you can't. You have to design a circuit that can be simulated. Make the voltage source non-ideal or make the capacitor non-ideal or insert a resistor between them. Etc.

I stuck a resistor between them to see what would happen, which was nothing.

Check off the UIC box on the .TRAN statement.

And that'll do it.  Very nice indeed. Let me post an image above.

You could change V2 to be a PULSE that has a time delay.  The PULSE in LTspice (yes, that is a good choice) can have user-defined rise and fall times.  But I am struggling to understand what you are trying to do with Q1, are you using it to switch the current in R2?  If so, I suspect its orientation is not quite right.

Name the nets you are plotting (and preferably the ones you might plot)- then the names will show up on the plots, don't go with the default LTspice numbering. It can change when you modify the circuit so even if you don't get confused initially, you soon will be. F4, type in a name that makes sense, and attach it to a net.  Q2 is connected in inverse so it will have very low hFE but I guess you know that. It's also good to use actual part models. The default PNP may not be very representative of a real discrete part.

@FabioBarone All I was trying to do was show that voltage on the base of the PNP would stop current from, flowing from the collector and emitter.  I'm just experimenting and having fun.

@TonyEnnis  In that case, be advised that (positive) current in the PNP between the emitter and collector terminal should flow in the direction of the arrow.  So as part of your experimentation, you may decide to flip it around.  Or try an NPN.  Oh, and you may like to increase the voltage at V2.  and possibly V1 also.  Anyway, have fun!

I will just toss out a random idea for you to play with, since you are just looking to play a bit. Keeping your PNP transistor (not changing it to NPN) and also keeping the \$1\:\text{V}\$ source as an idea here (I kind of see why you added that diode and I think it's not necessary if you use just one voltage supply), I'd suggest running this:

\$C_1\$ is initially uncharged (due to the UIC mentioned in the .TRAN card) and \$R_1\$ then supplies it some current as \$Q_1\$ stays on. Over time, \$C_1\$ gradually charges up and pinches off \$Q_1\$.
A slight improvement would be to include a resistor from \$V_1\$ to \$Q_1\$'s base, like this:

That provides a weak galvanic bypass across the emitter-base junction. In idealized circuit simulations, it may not make much of a difference. But if I were to build this, for real, I may likely include some large-valued \$R_3\$ there.
